# Best practice for updating cardano-node/cli?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I'm using a Linux VM on AWS and followed this guide: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node to install everything. What's the best way to go about updating the node and cli while preserving the wallets I've created?

Thanks, Myles

Answer (score 2):

Coincashew's guides are super helpful, especially this one on [how to update a stake pool.](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node/how-to-update-a-stakepool)

In short, you can either download the cardano-cli binaries directly, or build the new release from source in the same `git` directory as you built in the first time. Just make sure to rename the builds accordingly, and when you are done building, `sudo cp` the binaries into the user's `bin` directory; replacing the old binaries with the new ones.

Answer (score 2):

Your wallets have nothing to do with your cardano-node instances or binaries on a machine.
Having the wallet keys on a linux instance on AWS that is running cardano-node (and I assume has a public IP address) is from start a bad idea. Your keys should stay only on a computer where only you have access, in your home, and also as encrypted backups on USB sticks, for example.

Returning to your original question: the normal way of updating cardano-node and cardano-cli is to get the new binaries (you compile them from sources or you download the binaries provided by IOG - links on the releases page on Github), replace the existing binaries on your linux VM and restarting the cardano-node service. Sometimes there also changes to the config files, so it is always a good idea to check the release notes to see if you need to update the config files.

Comment: How do you go about updating the config files?

Comment: You download the latest configuration files from here: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html
and check if there are differences compared to your configuration files (except the topology file). If there are differences, you replace your configuration files with the new ones and restart the node. It is better to download them directly on the server(s) with wget, to be sure they are not altered when you download them. The genesis files are very sensitive, if you change anything in them, you will see errors in the logs. But they don't change, so you won;t need to update them.